# How can I stop my .htaccess file from including the full file path when testing locally?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I've built a website which uses the url to load pages from a database. The traffic is redirected to the `index.php` file, which then queries the url and loads the appropriate page. To make this work I'm using some rewrite rules in the `.htaccess` file.

Although I have been able to make this work in a live environment, I'm struggling to make it work locally, using XAMPP.

I'm using the following rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.png$ [NC]
# Various other exceptions

RewriteRule .* /index.php
```

Which are returning the following url

`http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/project-folder/localhost/project-folder/`

but I'd like the following page to be loaded:

`localhost/project-folder/index.php`

I can't understand where/why the full file path is being included, nor how I can exclude it.

Can anyone help?

Comment: A URL like `http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/project-folder/localhost/project-folder/` does not make any sense, that would mean that the http server is configured such that it uses the root of the server side file system as `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. That certainly is a huge security threat, it exposes the whole file system!

Comment: Your question is very vague... This _could_ mean that your application logic creates such broken URLs. That would be nothing the http server configuration can change, you will need to debug your own application (so your php code here).

Comment: Re: The security implications - I think that is just when I run the application on my laptop

Comment: FWIW I've changed the final line to `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` and it seems to have worked. Obviously great that the problem is solved, but I'm not sure I understand the difference